# Enterprise Java Beans Deployment

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, maven, javabeans

Good day, everyone!

I am studying JavaEE 6 with a book "Beginning JavaEE 6 with Glassfish 3" by Antonio Goncalves. And I faced a problem, I can't deploy my Remote Stateless Java Beans on Glassfish 3+ (glassfish-3.1.2.2), the following snippet represents one:

```
    ...
    @Stateless
    @LocalBean
    public class UserEJB implements UserEJBRemote {
        public User createUser(User anUser) throws IllegalArgumentException,
                                                   IllegalStateException,
                                                   PersistenceException {
            ...
        }

    public List<User> findAll() throws IllegalArgumentException,
                                       PersistenceException {
        ...
    } 

    public User findById(Long anId) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        return em.find(User.class, anId);
    } 

    public void removeByMail(String aUserMail) throws IllegalArgumentException, 
                                                      TransactionRequiredException {

        ...
    }

    public User update(User anUser) throws IllegalArgumentException, 
                                               TransactionRequiredException {

        return em.merge(anUser);                    
    }

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "NotebookUsers")
    private EntityManager em;
}
...
```

My `@Remote` interface declaration is :

```
...
@Remote
public interface UserEJBRemote {
    public User createUser(User anUser) throws IllegalArgumentException,
                                               IllegalStateException,
                                               PersistenceException;
public List<User> findAll() throws IllegalArgumentException,
                                   PersistenceException;

public List<User> findByName(String aUserName) throws IllegalArgumentException,
                                                      PersistenceException;

public User findById(Long Id) throws IllegalArgumentException;

public void removeByMail(String aUserMail) throws IllegalArgumentException, 
                                                  TransactionRequiredException ;

    public User update(User anUser) throws IllegalArgumentException, 
                                           IransactionRequiredException ;
}
...
```

Also I have a simple JUnit test:

```
    ...
    public class TestUserEJB {
    @BeforeClass
    public static void initialize() throws Exception {
        ec = EJBContainer.createEJBContainer();
        ctx = ec.getContext();
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void close() throws Exception {
        if(null != ec) {
            ec.close();
        }
    }

    @Test 
    public void testCreateAnUser() throws Exception {
        User testUser0 = new User();
        testUser0.setFirstname("Vova");
        testUser0.setSurname("Puchkov");
        testUser0.setMail("vasya.puchkov@gmail.com");
        testUser0.setPhoneNumber("8(777)6769990");

        UserEJB userEJB = (UserEJB) ctx.lookup("java:global/classes/UserEJB!" + 
            "beginning.javaee.notebook.UserEJB");       

        userEJB.createUser(testUser0);
        assertNotNull("ID should not be null", testUser0.getId());

        List<User> allUsers = userEJB.findAll();
        assertNotNull("Can't find users", allUsers);        
    }

    private static EJBContainer ec;
    private static Context ctx;
}
...
```

But after I had tried to build up my app with `mvn package` I got the following exception:

```
Nov 10, 2012 11:15:22 PM org.glassfish.ejb.embedded.EJBContainerProviderImpl createEJBContainer
SEVERE: ejb.embedded.exception_instantiating
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.getSingleton()Lorg/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder;
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.bind(LoggerFactory.java:121)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.performInitialization(LoggerFactory.java:111)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory(LoggerFactory.java:268)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:241)
    at org.hibernate.validator.util.LoggerFactory.make(LoggerFactory.java:29)
    at org.hibernate.validator.util.Version.<clinit>(Version.java:30)
    at org.hibernate.validator.engine.ConfigurationImpl.<clinit>(ConfigurationImpl.java:52)
    at org.hibernate.validator.HibernateValidator.createGenericConfiguration(HibernateValidator.java:43)
    at javax.validation.Validation$GenericBootstrapImpl.configure(Validation.java:269)
    at javax.validation.Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory(Validation.java:111)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.config.WriteableView.<init>(WriteableView.java:96)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.config.ConfigSupport.getWriteableView(ConfigSupport.java:202)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.config.ConfigSupport.getWriteableView(ConfigSupport.java:218)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.config.ConfigSupport._apply(ConfigSupport.java:154)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.config.ConfigSupport.apply(ConfigSupport.java:130)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.config.ConfigSupport.apply(ConfigSupport.java:109)
    at org.glassfish.scripting.jruby.sniffer.JRubySniffer.setup(JRubySniffer.java:151)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ContainerStarter.startContainer(ContainerStarter.java:99)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.setupContainer(ApplicationLifecycle.java:703)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.setupContainerInfos(ApplicationLifecycle.java:451)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer.prepareBundle(EarDeployer.java:264)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer.access$200(EarDeployer.java:79)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer$1.doBundle(EarDeployer.java:131)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer$1.doBundle(EarDeployer.java:129)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer.doOnBundles(EarDeployer.java:197)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer.doOnAllTypedBundles(EarDeployer.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer.doOnAllBundles(EarDeployer.java:232)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer.prepare(EarDeployer.java:129)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.prepareModule(ApplicationLifecycle.java:644)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:296)
    at org.glassfish.kernel.embedded.EmbeddedDeployerImpl.deploy(EmbeddedDeployerImpl.java:214)
    at org.glassfish.kernel.embedded.EmbeddedDeployerImpl.deploy(EmbeddedDeployerImpl.java:144)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.embedded.EJBContainerImpl.deploy(EJBContainerImpl.java:128)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.embedded.EJBContainerProviderImpl.createEJBContainer(EJBContainerProviderImpl.java:120)
    at javax.ejb.embeddable.EJBContainer.createEJBContainer(EJBContainer.java:102)
    at javax.ejb.embeddable.EJBContainer.createEJBContainer(EJBContainer.java:78)
    at beginning.javaee.notebook.TestUserEJB.initialize(TestUserEJB.java:18)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:45)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:42)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:27)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:30)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4TestSet.execute(JUnit4TestSet.java:53)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:123)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:104)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:164)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:110)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.invokeProvider(SurefireStarter.java:175)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.runSuitesInProcessWhenForked(SurefireStarter.java:107)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:68)
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 69.444 sec <<< FAILURE!
```

As I assume all the necessary dependencies were added in my `pom.xml`:

```
  <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>beginning.javaee.notebook</groupId>
  <artifactId>simple-ee-notebook</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>simple-ee-notebook</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.10</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
      <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
      <version>3.6.10.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.ejb</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.glassfish.extras</groupId>
      <artifactId>glassfish-embedded-all</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>


  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
        <configuration>
          <archive>
            <manifest>
              <mainClass>beginning.javaee.notebook.App</mainClass>
            </manifest>
          </archive>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <inherited>true</inherited>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.6</source>
          <target>1.6</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

I have been trying to decide that problem for several days but all is unsuccessfully. Thanks for help.
I added all the dependencies relating with `org.slf4j` and the problem was decided. Thanks again:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
  <version>1.6.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
  <version>1.6.1</version>
</dependency>
```

But I got a new problem:

```
    Nov 13, 2012 12:29:02 AM org.glassfish.api.ActionReport failure
SEVERE: Exception while invoking class org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer prepare method
java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'jdbc/NotebookUsersPoolDB' in SerialContext  [Root exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: NotebookUsersPoolDB not found]
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.PersistenceUnitInfoImpl.<init>(PersistenceUnitInfoImpl.java:111)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.PersistenceUnitLoader.loadPU(PersistenceUnitLoader.java:130)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.PersistenceUnitLoader.<init>(PersistenceUnitLoader.java:96)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer.prepare(JPADeployer.java:121)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.prepareModule(ApplicationLifecycle.java:644)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:296)
    at org.glassfish.kernel.embedded.EmbeddedDeployerImpl.deploy(EmbeddedDeployerImpl.java:214)
    at org.glassfish.kernel.embedded.EmbeddedDeployerImpl.deploy(EmbeddedDeployerImpl.java:144)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.embedded.EJBContainerImpl.deploy(EJBContainerImpl.java:128)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.embedded.EJBContainerProviderImpl.createEJBContainer(EJBContainerProviderImpl.java:120)
    at javax.ejb.embeddable.EJBContainer.createEJBContainer(EJBContainer.java:102)
    at beginning.javaee.notebook.TestUserEJB.initialize(TestUserEJB.java:24)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:45)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:42)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:27)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:30)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4TestSet.execute(JUnit4TestSet.java:53)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:123)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:104)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:164)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:110)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.invokeProvider(SurefireStarter.java:175)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.runSuitesInProcessWhenForked(SurefireStarter.java:107)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:68)
Caused by: javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'jdbc/NotebookUsersPoolDB' in SerialContext  [Root exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: NotebookUsersPoolDB not found]
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:442)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:392)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:392)
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.service.ConnectorResourceAdminServiceImpl.lookup(ConnectorResourceAdminServiceImpl.java:203)
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectorRuntime.lookupPMResource(ConnectorRuntime.java:429)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer$ProviderContainerContractInfoImpl.lookupDataSource(JPADeployer.java:228)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.PersistenceUnitInfoImpl.<init>(PersistenceUnitInfoImpl.java:108)
    ... 33 more
Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: NotebookUsersPoolDB not found
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.TransientContext.doLookup(TransientContext.java:197)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.TransientContext.lookup(TransientContext.java:168)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.TransientContext.lookup(TransientContext.java:172)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContextProviderImpl.lookup(SerialContextProviderImpl.java:58)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.LocalSerialContextProviderImpl.lookup(LocalSerialContextProviderImpl.java:101)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:430)
    ... 39 more
Nov 13, 2012 12:29:02 AM org.glassfish.api.ActionReport failure
SEVERE: Exception while preparing the app
java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'jdbc/NotebookUsersPoolDB' in SerialContext  [Root exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: NotebookUsersPoolDB not found]
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.PersistenceUnitInfoImpl.<init>(PersistenceUnitInfoImpl.java:111)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.PersistenceUnitLoader.loadPU(PersistenceUnitLoader.java:130)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.PersistenceUnitLoader.<init>(PersistenceUnitLoader.java:96)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer.prepare(JPADeployer.java:121)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.prepareModule(ApplicationLifecycle.java:644)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:296)
    at org.glassfish.kernel.embedded.EmbeddedDeployerImpl.deploy(EmbeddedDeployerImpl.java:214)
    at org.glassfish.kernel.embedded.EmbeddedDeployerImpl.deploy(EmbeddedDeployerImpl.java:144)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.embedded.EJBContainerImpl.deploy(EJBContainerImpl.java:128)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.embedded.EJBContainerProviderImpl.createEJBContainer(EJBContainerProviderImpl.java:120)
    at javax.ejb.embeddable.EJBContainer.createEJBContainer(EJBContainer.java:102)
    at beginning.javaee.notebook.TestUserEJB.initialize(TestUserEJB.java:24)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:45)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:42)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:27)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:30)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4TestSet.execute(JUnit4TestSet.java:53)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:123)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:104)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:164)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:110)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.invokeProvider(SurefireStarter.java:175)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.runSuitesInProcessWhenForked(SurefireStarter.java:107)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:68)
Caused by: javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'jdbc/NotebookUsersPoolDB' in SerialContext  [Root exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: NotebookUsersPoolDB not found]
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:442)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:392)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:392)
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.service.ConnectorResourceAdminServiceImpl.lookup(ConnectorResourceAdminServiceImpl.java:203)
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectorRuntime.lookupPMResource(ConnectorRuntime.java:429)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer$ProviderContainerContractInfoImpl.lookupDataSource(JPADeployer.java:228)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.PersistenceUnitInfoImpl.<init>(PersistenceUnitInfoImpl.java:108)
    ... 33 more
Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: NotebookUsersPoolDB not found
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.TransientContext.doLookup(TransientContext.java:197)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.TransientContext.lookup(TransientContext.java:168)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.TransientContext.lookup(TransientContext.java:172)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContextProviderImpl.lookup(SerialContextProviderImpl.java:58)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.LocalSerialContextProviderImpl.lookup(LocalSerialContextProviderImpl.java:101)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:430)
    ... 39 more
Nov 13, 2012 12:29:02 AM org.glassfish.ejb.embedded.EJBContainerProviderImpl createEJBContainer
INFO: [EJBContainerProviderImpl] Cleaning up on failure ...
Nov 13, 2012 12:29:02 AM org.glassfish.admin.mbeanserver.JMXStartupService shutdown
INFO: JMXStartupService and JMXConnectors have been shut down.
Nov 13, 2012 12:29:02 AM com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.AppServerStartup stop
INFO: Shutdown procedure finished
Nov 13, 2012 12:29:02 AM AppServerStartup run
INFO: [Thread[GlassFish Kernel Main Thread,5,main]] exiting
Nov 13, 2012 12:29:03 AM org.glassfish.ejb.embedded.EJBContainerProviderImpl createEJBContainer
SEVERE: ejb.embedded.exception_instantiating
javax.ejb.EJBException: Failed to deploy EJB modules - see log for details
    at org.glassfish.ejb.embedded.EJBContainerImpl.deploy(EJBContainerImpl.java:135)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.embedded.EJBContainerProviderImpl.createEJBContainer(EJBContainerProviderImpl.java:120)
    at javax.ejb.embeddable.EJBContainer.createEJBContainer(EJBContainer.java:102)
    at beginning.javaee.notebook.TestUserEJB.initialize(TestUserEJB.java:24)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:45)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:42)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:27)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:30)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4TestSet.execute(JUnit4TestSet.java:53)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:123)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:104)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:164)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:110)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.invokeProvider(SurefireStarter.java:175)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.runSuitesInProcessWhenForked(SurefireStarter.java:107)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:68)
```

All need jdbc resources are on the server, I checked that. They were created with the following commands:

```
/home/ilya/glassfishv3.1.2/bin/asadmin create-jdbc-connection-pool \
                                    --datasourceclassname=org.postgresql.ds.PGSimpleDataSource \
                                    --restype=javax.sql.DataSource \
                                    --property portNumber=5432:password=12345678:user=postgres:serverName=localhost:databaseName=postgres \
                                      NotebookUsersPool
/home/ilya/glassfishv3.1.2/bin/asadmin create-jdbc-resource --connectionpoolid NotebookUsersPool jdbc/NotebookUsersPoolDB
```

My `persistence.xml`

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="1.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" 
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence                                       
                      http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="NotebookUsers" transaction-type="JTA">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <jta-data-source>jdbc/NotebookUsersPoolDB</jta-data-source>
    <class>beginning.javaee.notebook.User</class>
    <properties>
<!--       <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="postgres"/>
      <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
      <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="12345678"/>
      <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres"/> -->
      <property name="hibernate.cache.provider_class" value="org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider"/>
      <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop"/>
      <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

The app server is running, and the database server is also running, but when I'm running the test, I'm getting a failed search of the 'jdbc/NotebookUsersPoolDB'. What's the problem? I haven't any idea.

Comment: You need correct versions of Slf4j. Take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5347912/slf4j-exception-with-quartz

Answer (score 0):

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.getSingleton()Lorg/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder;
```

implies that your code is calling a method that is not defined. Probably the code is exspecting a newer slf4j version than what is defined in your maven dependencies.

Try adding the following entries to your `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
<artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
<version>1.7.2</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
<artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
<version>1.7.2</version>
</dependency>
```